# Windows Vista Speech Recognition engine sampling rates

Tags: windows-vista, speech-recognition, wave, sampling

I need to recognize the speech from a set of WAV files that are not recorded on the computer doing the recognition. I know that if you recognize the speech from WAV files that are recorded at the same sampling rate as the recordings that the engine used for training, the results will be better.

But my questions is: what's the sampling rate for which Vista's engine was trained? I cannot seem to find this information anywhere.

And also... do you know any method to convert the WAV files from one sampling rate to another, from C#?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default sampling rate for the SAPI desktop engines is 11 KHz.  The desktop engines work well with any sampling rate above that.  Also, SAPI will resample the audio for you, if you use the [SpBindToFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717492(v=VS.85).aspx) helper.  You didn't mention which programming language you're using, so I assumed C++.